# How to Map json file in React

Tags: reactjs

> I map to json file in react js file i get an error:

```
const CompanyList = () => {
    const { REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT } = process.env;
    const [company, setCompany] = useState([]);
    const getCompanyData= async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`${REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT}/getCompanyList`, {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        })
        const content = await response.json();
        console.log(content);
        setCompany(content);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        getCompanyData();
    },[]);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>List of Companies</h1>
            {company.map((user) => (
        <div className="user">{user.companyId}</div>
      ))}
        </div>
    );
};
export default CompanyList;
```

> I get error this line {user.companyId}
> Property 'companyId' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)

This is my json data
(11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {companyId: 1, companyName: "COS Software Solutions PVT LTD", companyDescription: "Agile Development Company"}
1: {companyId: 2, companyName: "CTS", companyDescription: "Software Development Company"}
2: {companyId: 4, companyName: "TCS", companyDescription: "Consultancy Services"}
3: {companyId: 5, companyName: "HP", companyDescription: "Manufacturing Company"}
4: {companyId: 6, companyName: "Cogito", companyDescription: "Software"}
5: {companyId: 7, companyName: "Google", companyDescription: "Software Development Company"}
6: {companyId: 8, companyName: "AxisBank", companyDescription: "Financial based company"}
7: {companyId: 9, companyName: "makessoft", companyDescription: "softwaredevelopment company"}
8: {companyId: 10, companyName: "LG", companyDescription: "manufacturing company"}
9: {companyId: 11, companyName: "SoftMake", companyDescription: "IT Company"}

How to I bind user.CompanyId, user.CompanyName and user.CompanyDescription in any html element.

Comment: Please also include what `console.log(content);` is logging.

Comment: Mab be due to NULL check missing    { company.length > 0 && company.map((user) => (
        <div className="user">{user.companyId}</div>
      ))}

Comment: console.log(content). return the json response. My array value above mentioned.

Comment: console.log(content) return object only

Comment: add a console.log(company) above your return and check what is getting printed . It should print twice one with `[]` and the other with your `[{}, {} , {}]`  .

Comment: console.log(company) result is: (13) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {companyId: 1, companyName: "CES Software Solutions PVT LTD", companyDescription: "Agile Development Company"}
1: {companyId: 2, companyName: "CTS", companyDescription: "Software Development Company"}

Comment: [
  {
    "companyId": 1,
    "companyName": "CES Software Solutions PVT LTD",
    "companyDescription": "Agile Development Company"
  },
  {
    "companyId": 2,
    "companyName": "CTS",
    "companyDescription": "Software Development Company"
  },
  {
    "companyId": 4,
    "companyName": "TCS",
    "companyDescription": "Consultancy Services"
  }]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your are seeing is a TypeScript error telling you the variable `company` is of type `never`. The reason for this is that TypeScript can't infer the type of your variable from the initial value you provided `[]`.

You need to explicitly set the type by providing a type argument:

```
interface CompanyResponse {
   companyId: number
   companyName: string
   companyDescription: string
}

const CompanyList = () => {
    const { REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT } = process.env;
    const [company, setCompany] = useState<CompanyResponse[]>([]);
    ...
```

Comment: Now working fine. Thanks for correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Example of React Map Loop

```js
import React from 'react';  
    
function App() {  
    
 const students = [  
              {  
                'id': 1,   
                'name': Jack,   
                'email': 'jack@gmail.com'  
              },  
              {  
                'id': 2,   
                'name': 'Mary',   
                'email': 'mary@gmail.com'  
              },  
              {  
                'id': 3,   
                'name': 'John',   
                'email': 'john@gmail.com'  
              },  
          ];  
    
  return (  
    <div>  
        <h1> Example of React Map Loop </h1>  
     
        <table>  
            <tr>  
                <th>ID</th>  
                <th>Name</th>  
                <th>Email</th>  
            </tr>  
    
            {students.map((student, index) => (  
              <tr data-index={index}>  
                <td>{student.id}</td>  
                <td>{student.name}</td>  
                <td>{student.email}</td>  
              </tr>  
            ))}  
    
        </table>  
    
    </div>  
  );  
}  
    
export default App;
```